# Are the community files values available in community code/components?

Tags: community, configuration, files, community-builder

When setting up a community, these values can be set:

[image: Files fields]

It would be convenient if those values were accessible from code/components contained in the community e.g. for hints for users without the values having to be configured twice: once in the community setup and once in some other code/component configuration.

Is there any API that provides these values? I haven't found such an API